# How can you force a heap dump on a java-based web application that goes slowly in order to figure out where that slowness occurs?

Tags: java, memory

We are currently using a modified version of [Atlassian Confluence v.3.5](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/DOC/Confluence+3.5+Release+Notes)

and have created a space containing large number of pages (about 5000) and large number of attachments (about 10000).

When navigating to the home page of this big space it takes about 3 minutes to load completely (the safari web browser shows a spinning wheel indicating page resources are still being loaded).

In these 3 minutes, we are unable to determine where the processing time is being spent.

We turned on confluence's profiling feature but it did not help because there was not much output in the log file.

The confluence process (which is a java process) is using about 8.2% CPU during the 3 minutes.  How can I figure out what the process is doing?

Comment: Wouldn't a profiler that tells you in which functions the program is spending the most time be more appropriate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[You have all these options](http://www.fiveminutes.eu/java-heap-dump/):

1. HeapDumpOnCtrlBreak
2. HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError
3. Jmap
4. HotSpotDiagnosticMXBean

[A Thread Dump may also be useful.](http://helpx.adobe.com/cq/kb/TakeThreadDump.html)  You can use it to figure out what the threads are waiting on.

You can also use a profiler.  The best one I've used is [JProfiler](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&ved=0CEMQFjAB&url=http://www.ej-technologies.com/download/jprofiler/files&ei=DHeuUY69Bum6yAHRqYDgBw&usg=AFQjCNFQNRxqOpODkEVyCRQbq603wJTtrA&sig2=HCvyGZHUTNuaD7_BufUzTg&bvm=bv.47244034,d.aWc).  But there's other ones available that are free and open source.  I think netbeans comes with one.  And sun makes one called [VisualVM](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/visualvm/profiler.html).